# Query with multiple XOR

Tags: mysql, xor

I have a problem with MySQL. I have to select all the rows that meet only one condition. If the conditions are two XOR does the trick, but with more conditions it's not the solution. Must make these logical operations:

A:1 B:1 C:1 => 0
A:0 B:0 C:0 => 0
A:0 B:1 C:1 => 0
A:0 B:0 C:1 => 1
A:1 B:0 C:0 => 1
A:1 B:0 C:0 D:0 => 1
A:1 B:0 C:1 D:0 => 0

It must be true only if there is one condition true and the others false.

PS The number of conditions is variable

Comment: An XOR on booleans is nothing else than using the unequal operator (`<>` or `!=` in MySQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
WHERE IF(<cond1>, 1, 0)+IF(<cond2>, 1, 0)+(...)+IF(<condN>, 1, 0) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I would like to know why this simple and obvious expression won't work: «WHERE (msgSendType = 'to' XOR msgSendType = 'cc' XOR msgSendType = 'bcc' )» in MySQL?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve and what you mean by "won't work".

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where A+B+C+D = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested xors and then use count to see how many are satisfied? Just an idea here I don't exactly know the problem fully.